# Can I use getElementById() in a Maps infowindow in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, maps, getelementbyid, infowindow

I have an several markers placed on a Google Maps map and every marker has an infowindow with the following content:

```
            // Set the content of the infowindow of the marker.
            var infoContent =
              '<div id="iw-container" class="gm-style-iw">'+
                '<div class="iw-title">'+
                  '<p>{{place.name}}</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                // For each photo associated with this place, add it.
                '<div class="container-fluid">'+
                  {% for photo in place.photo_set.all %}
                    '<div class="row">'+
                      '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                        '<hr>'+
                        '<div class="">'+
                        // Check whether the attributes have a value and display them.
                          {% if photo.info != "" and photo.info != None  %}
                            '<p class="iw-info">{{ photo.info }}</p>'+
                          {% endif %}
                          {% if photo.year != "" and photo.year != None  %}
                            '<p class="iw-year">{{ photo.year }}</p>'+
                          {% endif %}
                          {% if photo.source != "" and photo.source != None  %}
                            '<p class="iw-source">Bron: {{ photo.source }}</p>'+
                          {% endif %}
                        '</div>'+
                        // Display the image with a link to the modal view.
                        '<div class="iw-image">'+
                          '<img id="{{ photo.id }}" class="iw-image" src="../static/images/{{ photo.image }}">'+
                        '</div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  {% endfor %}
                '</div>'+
              '</div>';
```

I want to add a modal view for every image in every infowindow, but I can not do this:

```
var img = document.getElementById("{{ photo.id }}");
```

This is because every time the img variable is Null.

Is it possible to access infowindow content with getElementById()?

Comment: Could this be because the html code for the infowindow is not already added when getElementById() gets called?

Comment: were you able to get any solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Where are you calling `document.getElementById("{{ photo.id }}")`?</s>

I was able to do something similar by returning a div with an Id in the InfoWidow and calling `document.getElementById()` in onMarkerClick.

Comment: Please provide only answers to the problem as new reply, you may comment the top post to ask question when needed.